# Vapor Client with Authentication

Tags: swift3, vapor

I need to auth on the server that I'm trying to pull data from I currently have it connecting to the server with:

```
    let urlString = "\(makeUrl(grammar: grammar))&\(query)"
    let drop = Droplet()

    return try drop.client.get(urlString)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get creds attached to the get request.  I tried just putting the user and password into the url but found the vapor client doesn't allow that:

```
    /*
      Userinfo (i.e., username and password) are now disallowed in HTTP and       
      HTTPS URIs, because of security issues related to their transmission
      on the wire.  (Section 2.7.1)
    */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little nudge from the Vapor Slack channel and a little code diving in the AlamoFire repo I have found the solution.

First you need to base64 encode the username name and password and then add it to the http header.

```
func performRequest(query: String, grammar: FMPGrammar) throws -> Response {

    let urlString = "\(makeUrl(grammar: grammar))?\(query)"

    let loginString = "\(userName):\(password)"
    let b64Login = Data(loginString.utf8).base64EncodedString(options: [])

    let drop = Droplet()
    let result = try drop.client.get(urlString, headers: [.authorization : "Basic \(b64Login)"])

    return result

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error states, it is a HUGE security risk to include username/password credentials in plaintext as GET uri parameters. You should (at a minimum) be sending them in a POST call.

Check out the blog post on [User Authentication with Vapor](https://theswiftwebdeveloper.com/user-authentication-with-vapor-b21e977aad68#.hqthgpe8v) to see a pretty decent example of setting up user authentication with Vapor. The blog is a little old now (Vapor has changed a lot since then), but I think pretty much everything in it should still work. At least conceptually.

Also, you join the Vapor Slack channel and ask questions in there :)
[qutheory.slack.com](http://qutheory.slack.com)